# Swift and Xcode immediate bug without changing anything

Tags: xcode, swift

No code needed except for the error, because I have noticed a bug with every project I have made so far. Im very new to Swift and Xcode so just keep that in mind.

Okay, so when I immediately start creating an app, I ran it (without changing a SINGLE thing) and an error occurred. It created the Iphone simulator, however, the output says

```
     SetAppThreadPriority: setpriority failed with error 45
```

and I have no clue what that means. When I add more and more items (such as buttons and labels) I get a new error and the actual app will crash and the output says

```
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
    (lldb)
```

also have no clue as to what that means either. Thanks for your help and let me know what you guys think!
(Just to let you know, I am running Xcode 6).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with the NSException. Right click on your button and make sure there is only one IBAction assigned to it. That was the issue with mine; I had changed the name of it so it assigned a second IBAction rather than replacing or renaming the original one.